# Setting visibility of button in wicket to false on submit

Tags: submit, wicket

so I have a wicket ajax submit link and I want to be able to set it to be not visible or disable it once it has been clicked. What can I do to achieve this behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that every 4th question here about Wicket is about visibility of components. Using the search function or google before ask is really that hard?

Comment: It seems to be that your comment is rude and unhelpful, perhaps you should learn to keep comments like this to yourself and move along. I have already followed the obvious routes to find out what I am doing wrong. I came here in the hope that people would show me multiple ways to do the same thing in the hope that one of the approaches would work for my use case. Instead I get your more than useless comment

Comment: You showed no piece of code, you did not mention any way you have tried, it looks like you didnt search on google: http://bit.ly/1biYgDK. You just wanted an ready solution. My comment was not targeted personally at you. Just my thoughts after answering a few question here. Instead you did get persoanlly.

Comment: And I'm currently uncertain how to help you further. Are you now able to hide your button? If not some piece of code/context would really help.

Comment: Yet my point still remains: if you have nothing to say that contributes towards the question then move along, your comments are no longer welcome please refrain from posting further.

Comment: @ThorstenWendelmuth Hello, I have yet to be able to get it to hide itself, the button itself is within a form that is within a listview, I am currently looking into whether my approcah to my specific use case is perhaps interfering with your solution (which was my initial solution as well) but it has been slow going. I am sorry for the lack of code but it is a case of I cannot release it without making substantial modifications to it.

Comment: Which Button do you use? AjaxLink, AjaxSubmitLink, SubmitLink? If you're using ajax, have you set outputMarkupId? Does the ajax debug window contain the corresponding id of the component you're trying to hide? Are you only refreshing the link or another component?

Comment: yes to all, I use the ajaxSubmitButton, I have now solved the issue by setting the visibility in a onConfigure method within the ajaxsubmitLink, this seemed to work; it did however require I rearrange some logic, I will accept your answer as the one that helped me solve the issue as the check list of what to check was helpful. Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink("link") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        setVisible(false);
        target.add(this);
    }
};
link.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(link);
```

Comment: does this work with submitlinks too as i have tried this and it does not seem to work

Comment: This works with the default "SubmitLink" as well. But you'll need to overwrite `onSubmit() / onError()` and you'll need a `Form` as well (and there will be no AjaxRequestTarget as the default SubmitLink isn't using ajax)